# X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.3

Tags: php, smtp, spam

I'm using PHPMailer to send mail from my server.

I have dkim=pass and SPF=pass on my outgoing emails. I am not listed on spamhaus blacklist or via the mxtoolbox blacklist. My emails usually don't go to spam.

However, today I noticed this line in the header of my outgoing mail:

```
X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.8
```

I'm concerned that this negative number will lead to my emails going to spam. (I'm assuming the negative number is bad, but I couldn't find any information online.)

Can someone shed some light on this? Is it a concern? If so, how do I improve this reading?
Thanks!!

Comment: I get score =-0.3. I wonder if that is good or bad. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The X-spam-status scores are put into the header of any email that passes through a mail server that is running Spamassassin (and some other anti-spam programs). [Here's](https://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_3_x.html) an article regarding tests Spamassassin does in version 3.3.

The higher the score the more likely the email is spam. It uses a range of things to decide on what is and isn't spam, blacklists are only part of its algorithms.

As listed [here](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/X_Spam_Status), an email can have a negative score if it is whitelisted, which is a good thing. If an email is whitelisted, this usually means (not always) that the recipient has received an email from the sender before, and the user has acted on that email (by acted on, I mean you have responded to it, or clicked "always show images from this sender" kind of thing) or you have that email address saved in your address book.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: In short, the negative number is good and you shouldn't worry about it.